# Comparar dois emails na hora do cadastro

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário de cadastro. Nele também existem dois campos que são email e confirmar email. Como faço para ver se os dois emails são iguais em php e exibir uma mensagem de erro, caso eles não sejam iguais?

Comment: Não seria `if ($email1 == $email2) { ... }`? Ficou bem vaga sua pergunta. Por favor, tem como [edit] e descrever melhor o que precisa fazer?

Comment: Não sei como perguntar isso melhor Anderson. Sou leigo, não se programar direito ainda. O que quero saber é se tem como comparar se dois e-mails estão certos na hora de fazer um cadastro sem utilizar javascript. Só usando php ou html. Como eu poderia ser mais claro? Pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Agora ficou mais confuso ainda. Você quer saber se dois e-mails são **iguais** ou se **estão certos**, no sentido de serem válidos? Você pode melhorar a pergunta descrevendo o que representa a sua aplicação e, principalmente, o formulário em questão. Por exemplo: "*tenho um formulário que faz o cadastro de novos usuários que possui um campo de e-mail, mas quero que quando o usuário digitar um e-mail errado aconteça X, etc*"

Comment: Acabo de editar Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recuperar os valores digitados no formulário no lado do servidor, com PHP, você pode utilizar a variável superglobal `$_POST`. Seria algo como:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$confirmacaoDeEmail = $_POST["confirmacao_de_email"];
```

E para verificar se são diferentes:

```
if ($email != $confirmacaoDeEmail) {
    echo "Os e-mails informados não coincidem";
}
```

Porém, isso não garante que os valores sejam, de fato, e-mails. O usuário poderia digitar o número 2 nos dois campos, que seriam iguais e não daria erro. Para validar se são e-mails válidos, você pode utilizar a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php):

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$confirmacaoDeEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "confirmacao_de_email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

// Verifica se são e-mails inválidos:
if (!$email || !$confirmacaoDeEmail) {
    echo "O e-mail não é um e-mail válido";
}

// Verifica se são diferentes:
if ($email != $confirmacaoDeEmail) {
    echo "Os e-mails informados não coincidem";
}
```

Mas reconsidere a utilização de JavaScript para fazer, **também**, essa validação ainda no lado do cliente, pois você evitaria do cliente fazer uma requisição desnecessária ao servidor. Quanto mais cedo você informar o usuário do erro, antes ele será corrigido.